# How to uninstall "Microsoft AU Daemon” from my macOS machine?

Tags: ms-office, macos

How do I completely remove "Microsoft AU Daemon” from my macOS machine?

I don't want to disable it. I want to **remove it completely** from my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find it in Terminal with

```
mdfind -name "application name"
```

once you have it (copy its location and now kill it with

```
sudo rm -rif paste
```

there is no undo so be precise what and where are you deleting